# can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python

Okay I'm trying to pull the top 5 definers in the dictionary but I keep getting this error:

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

On the following code:

```
def top():
   datalist = sorted(Dictionary.dWord.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
   t = 1
   tops, nums,dftop5 = [], [], []
   for l in datalist:
      if l[1] not in tops:
        tops.append(l[1])
        nums.append(str(l[1][1]))
        if t == 5: # edit here
          break
        t+=1
   for i, (top, num) in enumerate(zip(tops, nums)):
      dftop5.append(top+": ("+num+" define(s)")
   return dftop5
```

The setup on the Dictionary.dWord.items() are like this:

```
{'testword': ('charles', 1, 'this is a test', 1389116045)}

Dictionary.dWord[word] = name, numdef, definition, wordtime
```

It's suppose to get the name and numdef.

Comment: I 'fixed' the string in the `top.append()` line, your quotes were unbalanced. You may want to fix that properly, albeit that it is not the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort key function is incorrect:

```
datalist = sorted(Dictionary.dWord.items(), key=lambda x: x[2][0], reverse=True)
```

`x` is a reference to a `key, value` tuple, which means you need to address `x[1]` to access the value:

```
datalist = sorted(Dictionary.dWord.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
```

Your `datalist` loop then makes the same mistake trying to access `l[2][0]` instead of `l[1][0]`.

Comment: Will l[1][0] get the numdefs? Because the order is Dictionary.dWord[word] = name, numdef, definition, wordtime.

Comment: You have a list of `(key, value)` tuples here, not just the dictionary values.

Comment: So how would I fix it?

Comment: Your `tops` list now holds the value tuples; did you mean to use `l[1][1]` instead of `l[1]`?

Comment: I think. I was trying to get the name value

Comment: Each `l` is a key-value pair, `l[1]` is the value, `l[1][1]` is the `numdef` entry of your value tuple.

Comment: Oh I gotcha. I see whatcha mean now.